# Exception can't be caught by process.on("uncaughtException")

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following code in index.js

```
const winston = require('winston');
require('winston-mongodb');

process.on('uncaughtException', (ex) => {
  console.log('WE GOT AN UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION');
  winston.error(ex.message, ex);
});
```

Here's how I expect it to work. The index.js will raise an uncaught exception.Then the console.log will print the message and the winston library will log the error and will store it in it's logfile.

In reality however none of the above works.Not even the console.log. So I suppose that the error is never raised.

I use: node -> v10.15.1
npm -> 6.4.1
winston ->2.4.0
winston-mongodb ->3.0.0

Comment: I'm a little bit confused just for clarification the error is thrown but **NOT** logged by winston or the error should get thrown but is **NEVER** raised?

Comment: The error is never raised. If it was raised I suppose it would be logged in winston! I tried without winston too. Only the console.log command but it didn't work.

Comment: Okay what error do you expect and why? It sounds stupid but the error is that no one is raised? You are also printing to console do you see this message?

Comment: Yes i know its stupid! Indeed the error is that no error is raised. Console.log doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry but then this question is **not** clear enought... Please provide the type and reason of error you're expecting and maybe also the winston config. Moreover ensure it's **clear** that you expect a missing error. Please **update** your question.

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: Why would the index.js raise an exception ?

Comment: @Giannis "uncaughtException" is an event connected to your callback function. But if never an error is thrown and it seems like this, the callback and so winston is never called... So either provide the full code or give the lines which should throw an error!

Comment: @0x1C1B you are right. I forgot the line "throw new Error()". Thats why it didn't raise an error. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Seblor you are right. I forgot the line "throw new Error()". Thats why it didn't raise an error. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Giannis Please provide full **CODE** and **OUTPUT**, **UPDATE** the question with these information. However I guess you're throwing the error before registering the event handler right? The default behaviour is printing the stack trace. Because your error is thrown before setting a custom behaviour your behaviour will never apply and the default one is used!

Comment: @0x1C1B Indeed! I tried that and it's working! Thank you for your solution!